# Does BeautifulSoup work on IronPython?

Tags: .net, beautifulsoup, ironpython

Does Beautiful Soup work with Iron Python?

If so with which version of Iron Python? How easy is it to distribute a windows desktop app on .net 2.0 using Iron Python (mostly C# calling some python code for parsing html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most purely Python modules work with Iron Python. If it contains C, it will not work, most likely. From a quick look at the source code, you can find that BeautifulSoup4 is purely Python. Therefore, it is most likely compatible with IronPython. Hope I could help.